Replace any number of spaces with a single underscore
How it is possible, using zmv, to replace any number of spaces with a single underscore?
What I use currently is
zmv -- '* *' '$f:gs/ /_'

but it replaces each space, and so foo   bar.txt become foo___bar.txt, not foo_bar.txt (which I would it to be).

What you want here is the equivalent of the regexp + operator which in zsh with extendedglob on (and zmv does enable extendedglob) is the ## glob operator.
The :s/.../.../ modifier from csh doesn't do pattern matching unless you set the histsubstpattern option. zmv doesn't set that option and resets the options to a sane default, so you can't use it there. The next version of zsh (whether that's 5.10 or 6.0) will have :S (actually on my request and for that very purpose) which does pattern matching unconditionally, so with those, you'll be able to do:
zmv '* *' '$f:gS/ ##/_'

But with any version of zsh, you can also use the ksh-style ${param//pattern/replacement} instead:
zmv '* *' '${f// ##/_}'

Note that -- is not necessary here as the first argument doesn't start with -.

Many thanks, Stéphane. I have noticed that you put -- even when it is not necessary (for consistency, I suppose), and I adopted your practice.

"The next version of zsh will have :S" - Could you show how it will work with :S?

@jsx97, see edit.

And to make it replace not only single spaces, but also space-hyphen-space (so that foo - bar become foo_bar, I should use zmv -- '* *' '${f//( #-## #| ##)/_}', correct?

Yes, though as it also replaces the hyphens that are not surrounded by spaces, it would probably make more sense to do zmv '*[- ]*' '${f//( #-## #| ##)/_}' or just zmv '*' '${f//( #-## #| ##)/_}'
